# php - page doesn't redirect properly when loging-in success

Tags: php, session

Here is my code:
I have started the session at the top of the page index.php already
`

```
if(isset($_POST['btsubmit'])){
    $username=$_POST['txtname'];
    $password=$_POST['txtpass'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbuser WHERE AccountName='$username' AND Password='$password'";  
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if($username="" or $password=""){
        echo"Your box is empty";
    }else{      
        if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $_SESSION['AccountName']= $row['AccountName'];
            header("Location: welcome.php");
            exit();
        }else{
            echo "fail";
        }

    }
}
```

?>`
When I login success, it does not redirect to the page welcome.php, it stays at index.php the same. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Is it possible that your session isnt working, and you are redirected to welcome but then straight back to index?

Comment: You need to use `session_start()` on the file which has the above code, and on `welcome.php` right after `<?php`. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. At least, use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape the variables you are going to use in SQL queries. You should use comparison operator `==` not assignment `=` one when you check if `$username` or `$password` are empty.

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn **Offtopic** Also you should put `limit 1` at the end of your query or check for multiple users when the result is back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

To build on my comment:

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     mysql_select_db("myphone",$con);

    if(isset($_POST['btsubmit'])){
        $username=(!empty($_POST['txtname']))?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtname']):false;
        $password=(!empty($_POST['txtname']))?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtpass']):false;
        if($username===false || $password===false){die('Username or password is blank!');}

        $sql="SELECT AccountName FROM tbuser WHERE AccountName='$username' AND Password='$password' LIMIT 1";  
        $query=mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)==1){
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $_SESSION['AccountName']=$row['AccountName'];
            $_SESSION['LoggedIn']=TRUE;
            header("Location: ./welcome.php");
            exit();
        }else{
             echo "Fail";
        }  
    }              
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is because of your if condition `if($username="" or $password=""){` This should be == instead of =. Because of this, it never goes to the else part of the code. 
Alse, is it your actual code ? You are first making DB query and after that checking if username/password input was empty.

Probably you should first check if both inpts are not empty then you should make query, and if the query is successful, then you should redirect to the welcome page.